# How can I get awk to print both matches and non-matches?

Tags: bash, awk

Basically, all I want to do is alter outputs if the input matches a filter, but the part being altered isn't what is being filtered (or I would use `sed`). The problem so far is that my `awk` is only outputting the altered lines.

Quick example, put this in test.txt:

```
orange beet pear cowmilk
apple pear berry cowmilk
orange melon cherry cowmilk
```

If I use the code:

```
awk /orange/'{gsub(/cow/,"cow~"); print}' test.txt
```

I get:

```
orange beet pear cow~milk
orange melon cherry cow~milk
```

When I would rather get:

```
orange beet pear cow~milk
apple pear berry cowmilk
orange melon cherry cow~milk
```

I see you can do `||` with awk, but I haven't been able to figure out how to make that fit with the gsub above.

For bonus appreciation, what I'd really like to do is add color instead of `~`, but that totally breaks, i.e.

```
awk /orange/'{gsub(/cow/,"cow'\e[1;34m'"); print}' test.txt
```

gives me an error about `\` not being the end of the line.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For colour, you need to specify the actual ESC character (not the escaped form `\e`).. the value is hex `\x1B` or octal `\033`. The following scripts colour the dash `-` and print all input lines

```
awk '/orange/{gsub(/cowmilk/,"cow\x1B[1;34m-\x1B[0mmilk")} {print}' "$file"

sed '/orange/{s/cowmilk/cow\x1B[1;34m-\x1B[0mmilk/g}' "$file"
```

Comment: Ah, great! Thanks. I didn't realize just sed could do this too.

Answer (score 5):

For printing each line after modifying only a few, add a separate condition that always evaluates to true, like (`1`):

```
awk '/orange/{gsub("cow", "cow~")} 1' "$file"
```

You could also have `{print}` explicitly:

```
awk '/orange/{gsub("cow", "cow~")} {print}' "$file"
```

Remember that each awk statement consists of a condition and a statement clause:

```
condition {statements}
```

But each of these is optional, if you do not include *`{statements}`*, then `{print}` is used.  If you do not include *`condition`*, then `1` is used.